# How can I print a certain string i times in a for loop?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

i'm trying to print out a shape that looks something like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

To do that i'm using a for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  System.out.print("*");
  System.out.println;
}
```

but how do I get the line 2 to print i asterisks, instead of just the one asterisk as i have so far?

Comment: Well, `for` loops are able to repeat things a specific number of time. Keep thinking.

Comment: One hint, use nested for loops i.e. one for loop within other for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you want to articulate here is that, for each row, print as many asterisks as the current row number.  Nested loops can be used here:

```sql
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {       // the row
    for (int j=0; j <= i; ++j) {  // the column
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 11 or greater you can use [public String repeat​(int count)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ){
            System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace('\0', '*'));
}
```

to print `*` according to the value `i` contains each time it loops

It basically creates a new char array of size `i` and replaces all the nulls , i.e.('\0'), with `*` of that char array, and then it converts the char array into one single string and prints it.

Comment: Giving the OP an answer to early cs student homework is not helping.

Comment: then the simplest is to refer the answer by @Tim Biegeleisen, but if you break down my answer, its just 2 simple tasks done through one line, created a char array of size i, replaces the array with *, convert it to one string

Comment: I say again.  People learn by thinking, not by copying a (not very good) solution.

Comment: Since no Java version has been specified, I’d assume an up-to-date one and use `"*".repeat(i)` instead of `new String(new char[i]).replace('\0', '*')`. Otherwise: `StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) System.out.println(s.append("*"));` This new-array-then-replace-nul-with-char trick looks creative, but has no real advantage. Another alternative would be `String s = "*****"; for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));`